# how to perform OR operator using Parse API in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using "parse.com" for storing data. I want to retrieve the objects in which its "EndDate" is "greaterThanOrEqualTo" current date OR "lessThanOrEqualTo" to array of dates(say Arrival Dates). But while retrieving the objects using "orQueryWithSubqueries" of parse it is crashing.

**Example:** End date is 17 may. current date is 15 may arrival dates are 22 may and 26 may..

17 may should be compared with 15 may and array of dates(22 may and 26 may).

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TVTrip"];

 PFQuery *newquery=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TVTrip"];

 PFObject *userobj= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TVUser"];

    userobj.objectId=[somedefaults objectForKey:@"userid"];

    [query whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:userobj];

     [newquery whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:userobj];


    NSDateFormatter *tempdateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];


    NSString *abrvstr=[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone ] abbreviation];
    NSInteger gmttimeinterval=[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone ] secondsFromGMT];

     [tempdateformat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd,yyyy"];
    [tempdateformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:gmttimeinterval]];
    // [tempdateformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone ]];
    NSString *datestr=[tempdateformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

     NSLog(@" check the date to fetch %@",datestr);


    datestr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, 0:0",datestr];

    [tempdateformat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd,yyyy, H:m"];

    NSTimeZone *temmmmzone=[[NSTimeZone alloc]init];
    NSTimeInterval startdatetimeint=[temmmmzone daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate:[NSDate date]];
    [tempdateformat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:startdatetimeint ]];

    //[query whereKey:@"EndDate" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[tempdateformat dateFromString:datestr]];

if (tripPlanFlightArray.count>0)
    {

        for (int i=0; i<tripPlanFlightArray.count; i++)
        {
            PFObject *flightObj=[tripPlanFlightArray objectAtIndex:i];

            // [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

            // [formatter setDateFormat:@"h:m a"];
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"];

            NSDate *enddate = [flightObj objectForKey:@"ArrivalDate" ];

            [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:startdatetimeint ]];

            [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];

            NSString *endString = [formatter stringFromDate:enddate];

            NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@End date is:%@",endString);

            [query whereKey:@"EndDate" lessThanOrEqualTo:[formatter dateFromString:endString]];

        }
        [newquery whereKey:@"EndDate" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[tempdateformat dateFromString:datestr]];

    }
    else
    {
        [query whereKey:@"EndDate" greaterThanOrEqualTo:[tempdateformat dateFromString:datestr]];
    }

    NSLog(@"check the time actual fetching %@",[tempdateformat dateFromString:datestr ]);

    [query whereKey:@"TripDeleteBool" notEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query includeKey:@"UserId"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"StartDate"];

    [newquery whereKey:@"TripDeleteBool" notEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [newquery includeKey:@"UserId"];
    [newquery orderByAscending:@"StartDate"];

    //query.limit = 3;
    // NSLog(@"**** %@ **** ",[query findObjects]);

    //PFQuery *query_final = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[newquery,query]];

    NSArray *arrQuery = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:newquery,query, nil];

    PFQuery *querydata = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:arrQuery];

    [querydata findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *arrRes,NSError *error) {

        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"All data is = %@",arrRes);
        }
        else
        {
            NSlog(@"Error");
        }
    }];
```

While retrieving the data of "querydata" it is crashing. Please suggest where I am going wrong. I *Google* about it but nothing works for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the error saying? Add exception breakpoint from breakpoint navigator in Xcode and you may see the error message.

Comment: @knshn..I have kept exception breakpoint..Not getting any error message..